# Can I get GPS data into my Nikon RAW files at time of capture?

Tags: nikon, gps, geotagging

On a Nikon DSLR such as the D7000 which doesn't have integrated GPS, is it possible to add some sort of accessory to the camera which will embed GPS data into the files at time of capture?

I see a couple other good questions about adding GPS data ([What GPS would you recommend...](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3675/what-gps-would-you-recommend-for-geo-tagging) and [What options do I have for GPS/Geotagging...](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/what-options-do-i-have-for-gps-geotagging-with-a-digital-slr)) but both of them go down the path of using an external GPS unit and then using software to sync the data during post-processing.  I'd prefer to eliminate this step if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally use my Android device to record a track and then tag the images in Lightroom as discussed here:
http://www.earthboundlight.com/phototips/adobe-lightroom-geotagging.html

Now that I have been doing that I can see why you want to get a device:-)  The nikon mailing list has discussed this before and several people have used a di-gps device:
http://www.dawntech.hk/di-GPS/index.htm

One such discussion on D1iscussion can be found here:
http://www.d1scussion.com/thread/202788/#r202802

Nikon makes one:
http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/GPS/25396/GP-1-GPS-Unit.html#tab-ProductDetail.ProductTabs.CompatibleWith

While trying to find the di-gps I also found this:
http://blog.gerardprins.com/blog2.php/2009/06/05/competition-nikon-gp1-promote-gps-d90

Answer (score 5):

Nikon has a special GPS unit, the [GP-1](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/GPS/25396/GP-1-GPS-Unit.html).

In urban areas (where there are Wi-Fi networks in range) you could use [EyeFi](http://uk.eye.fi/products/prox2) Geo/Explore/Pro memory/WiFi cards which perform [geotagging](http://uk.eye.fi/how-it-works/features/geotagging) automatically using WPS data when uploading the data.

Answer (score 2):

The Nikon device is quite expensive (USD 230) in comparison with other real-time geo-tagging units, such as Geometr, Solmeta and Promote (± USD 150). 
Also, Nikon does not reveal the origin of its gps chip, which leaves at least reasonable doubt about it's effectiveness.
Most third party units use the latest generation SiRF Star III, which is extremely fast at locking in on satellites, and generally maintains locking even indoor, under tree cover or heavy clouding.
Most Nikon's - apart of the so-called Babies - include a geo-tagging device connection, be that the 10 pin remote or a dedicated port; no other camera brand except for Fuji currently allows for real time geo-tagging. For more information you might want to read this:
http://blog.gerardprins.com/blog2.php/2009/04/29/geotagging-for-nikon-review-promote-gps
http://blog.gerardprins.com/blog2.php/2009/06/05/competition-nikon-gp1-promote-gps-d90

All recent Nikon cameras, including the (baby) D3100, allow for real time geo-tagging.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this, but Nikon does sell a "GP-1 GPS Unit" that connects to the camera. According to the manual it does record the GPS information with the image.