# Will DSLR models support built-in geotagging in the next year?

Tags: dslr, geotagging, features

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What options do I have for GPS/Geotagging  with a digital SLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/what-options-do-i-have-for-gps-geotagging-with-a-digital-slr)

I have a Panasonic DMC-TZ10 and what I really love about the cam is the build-in geo tagging. Now I'm planning to buy a DSLR camera, and saw that none of the actual products has built-in geo tagging.

I was wondering if it's realistic that, let's say, Canon/Nikon will implement this in the new models in the next year, or is it something that will never find place in a DSLR cam?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/what-options-do-i-have-for-gps-geotagging-with-a-digital-slr

Comment: It's an interesting question in general, but please see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130/should-we-allow-questions-about-unreleased-cameras

Comment: I flagged this as off-topic. The FAQ says that this site is not about [unreleased equipment](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130/should-we-allow-questions-about-unreleased-cameras).

Comment: I voted to close because the question either forces speculation about unreleased products, or if the question is changed to address GPS in dSLRs *right now* it becomes a duplicate of the question @ieure cited...

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of the question @ieure linked, given that there *are* indeed cameras on the market that have built-in GPS, and speculative equipment recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's hard to speculate about what may or may not be included in future models** (you won't get a definite answer), but thus far neither manufacturer has seemed interested in adding that functionality into a DSLR.  Nikon makes it relatively easy to add a separate GPS accessory unit (the [GP-1](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/GPS/25396/GP-1-GPS-Unit.html)) to most of its current and recent DSLRs; to my knowledge with Canon you need to use a third party solution.

Regardless of manufacturer, you can use a separate GPS tracking device and ensure that the camera's time is synced with the GPS time and then use software to match/add the GPS information once you have the photos on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see this in DSLR's myself as a Canon user! I've no experience with this but Nikon sells a geotagging unit which is compatible with some of their DSLR's:

http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/GPS/25396/GP-1-GPS-Unit.html#tab-ProductDetail.ProductTabs.Overview

Answer (score 1):

You could just buy **a separate GPS tracker and the sync it with your images**. With this you don't need to speculate when companies are going to release a GPS enable camera.
Also this device will be compatible forever (As long RAW and JPG specifications don't change).

I've got a [Gisteq Phototrackr](http://www.gisteq.com/PhotoTrackr/phototrackr-dpl700.php) and it's quite awesome. Does it job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to [search for DSLR cameras with GPS capabilities built-in](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?size=slr&gps=1&by=feature) and you can see there are currently two, both from Sony.

Of course we speculate about other brands but the few people who know for sure won't tell us.

There are lots of ways to get GPS tagging to a DSLR without a built-in GPS. Add-on units such as the one pointed to in another answer let the cameras tag photos directly but you can also tag photos later using a stand-alone GPS or even a phone with GPS capabilities.