# What on-camera geotagger do you recommend for a Nikon DSLR?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, geotagging, nikon-d700

I'm looking to purchase an on camera geo tagging device. I currently have [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001PO5VV8) for my Nikon D40. I'm upgrading to the Nikon D700 which is compatable with on body gps devices, and I'd rather not have to go through the process I do now. Which requires me to be at home on my PC to tag raw files (sony gps doesn't work with my macbook) and I also have to spend a decent amount of time convertingfile types, organizing gps files and making sure no photos have been missed or why there were out of the time range.

I've done a decent amount of reading, and have three options.

[Nikon's GP-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001FA0FTK) which some reviews have complained about how much battery it drains and that it can't get a good lock indoors. Another complaint is that it doesn't have an on/off switch. What has your experience been? Does it have good qualities that outweigh these bad review points?

Promote's GPS-N-1 It seems to have the best reviews so far, and is the one I'm thinking of getting. There was one case where the reviewer said it had broken after about a year, but Promote repaired it even though it was out of warrenty. amazon . com /Promote-Systems-Receiver-GPS-N-1-Digital/dp/B001GGBGNM/

Columbus nGPS I found this one today, and it has pretty good reviews, and looks like it has the ability to be charged so that you can attach it to your strap, and still use your on camera flash which could be nice. amazon . com /Columbus-nGPS-Remote-Cord-Combo/dp/B002UWNHDS/

What are your thoughts on the three? Do you have an other reccomendations?

Sorry about the last two links I couldn't post more than two...

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1306/21

Comment: @Rowland Shaw I saw that thread it mentions the method I currently use. A cheap GPS and GPIsync but with having the option of going with an onboard tagger it rather than than all the extra that comes with doing through GPIsync

Answer (score 2):

From Ebay I purchased a MetaGPS http://www.metagps.com/ After reading good reviews.  I have it on my D7000 and used it extensively on my trip to Thailand (http://maxphotoblog.com/photo.aspx/Details/max/dsc4894).  You can see the location properly mapped on the right, while I was moving.  I don't have experience with others but this one works great as long as you remember to charge it.

Comment: The MetaGPS looks a lot like one I use for Civil Air Patrol photos - as long as it gets a fix before a flight, it maintains tracking through our entire flight. The trick with Nikon cameras seems to be to turn off the "sleep" on the metering system so that it doesn't have to redo the GPS lock. YMMV and all that, but that's what works for us.

Comment: Yes I have to turn off the sleep on my D7000 as well.