# What on-camera geotagger do you recommend for a Canon DSLR?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, geotagging

I have been looking for a solution for geotagging with my Canon DSLR (T2i). It seems the most common solution is to use a separate standalone GPS unit and adding the tags in later during processing (As suggested in [What options do I have for GPS/Geotagging with a digital SLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/what-options-do-i-have-for-gps-geotagging-with-a-digital-slr)).

I would prefer to have an on-camera solution for my camera, as honestly it will just make life easier for me, giving me one less thing to have to do.

*Note: this question is in much the same vein as [What on-camera geotagger do you recommend for a Nikon DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13935/what-on-camera-geotagger-do-you-recommend-for-a-nikon-dslr), just for Canon instead.*

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1306/21

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you're stuck with having to apply the information after you import the photos to your computer. Fortunately, this is inexpensive. Take your smartphone or other GPS and record your journey and make sure your camera's clock is sync'd with the GPS device (or close to it) and then use pretty much any of the available software to merge the data (personally, I use Lightroom 4)

If you want all the built in fanciness then you need to buy a more expensive camera. Sorry.

Comment: Ouch. That is what I was afraid of, it just not in the cards for a more expensive camera at the moment, maybe in the future. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

So far it's only a very limited number of Canon EOS cameras that support geotagging when shooting. Unless you have a 7D, 5D Mk III or 1D X, you need an external logger and then match the pictures with the log back home.

Canon have two GPS-units, [GP-E1](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/gps_receivers/gps_receiver_gp_e1) (only for 1D X) and [GP-E2](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/gps_receivers/gps_receiver_gp_e2) (for all three cameras).