# Suggestions for an easy way to add gps data to jpegs

Tags: jpeg, gps, locations

I am looking for an easy way to add locate and add GPS data to  JPG files on  a Mac running OS Catalina.

I would like the photo data to be able to be recognized in iPhone picture maps and location search.
I do not use Photos or aperture app.

Suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What options do I have for GPS/Geotagging  with a digital SLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/what-options-do-i-have-for-gps-geotagging-with-a-digital-slr)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [geotag](http://geotag.sourceforge.net/) software. This is java software and should run on your Mac machine.

1. Load photos (drag and drop may work)
2. In case of need you can adjust time/timezone of photos
3. Then File->Load tracks from file
4. Select images you want to write location
5. Right click, Save new location->Selected images

Comment: note there may be some hoop-jumping required to get Java running on Catalina - https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk-jre-macos-catalina.html Java has been switched off by default on Mac for quite a few years.

Comment: Same is on Windows, Linux. There is no free lunch

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it in adobe Lightroom.  I add my photos to my LR catalogue by importing them to the catalogue. Go to the map portion of the program - the photos will stay displayed in the filmstrip on the bottom of the screen. In the map search bar at top, type in where the photo was taken then the map comes up in the window. I select the photos I want to mark then drag and drop them where I want them on the map. That populates the gps field with coordinates. I them save the metadata to the files, command S I believe on Mac, and that's it.  tks all!    UPDATE:

So unfortunately I did not have good luck so far w/ LR.  The pics I have to work on are old and have basically no metadata showing except for the date taken, or as Finder shows it, Content Created.  I add the photos to the LR catalog and make my location changes.  As soon as I save the metadata to file, the Created and Modified dates change to the date of the metadata update in the Mac Finder and Get Info panels.  Also, the only way I could get the Date Created field in LR to stick was to apply the date by using a Custom Preset entry.  Each time I did the date change either on Add or added it after the addition to the LR catalog, it did not stay.

Update 2:  so another user suggested this and it has worked so far. I re-imported the pictures into LR and from the Library window then edited the time/date from the metadata drop down menu, Edit Capture Time, ^X,  to have the capture time/date “original” and “corrected” time the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the Photos app which comes with all Macs, you can select the photo and click the info icon (circle with an i in it or else type CMD-i) and then edit the meta data including adding location data. In fact, you can select multiple photos and edit the location for the group. I haven't tested it, but I'm assuming you can then export the pictures as JPEG and the location info will remain.

[image]

Comment: tks.  I had a typo above, I put iPhoto but meant photos app.  I dont use it.

Comment: But you could use it to set the location info. No one says you have to store your images in it permanently.

Comment: no.  I said I don't use it.  so I cant use a program to do something if I don't use it.  why would I want to learn a new program ive never used and don't understand to potentially change my file formats or whatever if I don't use it in the 1st place only to have to potentially use it then have to export all the photos out of it ?

Comment: @Stumped - "*Suggestions?*" I suggest,  Instead of telling us what software you are unwilling to learn, you   tell us what software you actually HAVE  and/or ARE willing to learn. **Informed answers require informed questions**.

Comment: @Stumped If you had simply told us you use Lightroom, we could have told you it has the capability built in.

Comment: Yes - funny no one suggested though, Eric.

Comment: Alaska man - I did do some research first before I posted. I thought I was being thorough in listing the software I do not use so as not to waste others time in covering stuff I do not use. I did not know LR had that capability until I saw it on another site and I did then post about here and the. Also edited my list to cover what I did. No one has even yet to comment on it - mostly,e bc I already answered understandably.   To list every software program a user has is unrealistic and I have never seen that on any of these sites.

Comment: PS -  sorry...  to be clear, I am not a frequent user of LR and quite frankly forgot I had it so it was not an obvious 1st choice for me or previous posters I guess.

Comment: @Stumped The reason no one suggested LR is that it requires a paid subscription and would be massive overkill unless you already had it.

Comment: O. Thank you...